# Automatic Slicer Selection VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dashboard, slicers

I am trying to automate my dashboard as efficient as possible. For that i need my slicer to automatically select this month and the previous month.

Currently it manually updates by a different macro for every month, which deselects everything except the months in scope.

[image: Manual Code.png]

Doing it this  way gives the dashboard performance issues.
It doesn't matter if it works with formulas or VBA.

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Month()` and `DateAdd()` to determine the current and previous months.

```
Sub MTDSelectThisMonthAndPreviousMonth()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents -False
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Datenschnitt__Month__Int___Invoice_Date1")
        .Slicerltems("1").Selected = False
        .Slicerltems("2").Selected = False
        .Slicerltems("3").Selected = False
        .Slicerltems("4").Selected = False
        .Slicerltems("5").Selected = False
        .Slicerltems("6").Selected = False
        .Slicerltems("7").Selected = False
        .Slicerltems("8").Selected = False
        .Slicerltems("9").Selected = False
        .Slicerltems("10").Selected = False
        .Slicerltems(" 11 ").Selected = False
        .Slicerltems("12").Selected = False
        .Slicerltems(Month(Date)).Selected = True
        .Slicerltems(Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Date))).Selected = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the incovenience.
Thank you very much for your work.